# Define table in select query from the value of a text box

Tags: ms-access, select

I have a very basic select query in MS Access. The only variable is that I want the user to select the region from a drop down list (combo box). There is a different table for each region, so I want the FROM field to pull from the combo box.

My query looks like this:

```
    SELECT
       STOCK_CODE, STOCK DESCRIPTION

    FROM
       Forms![frm_MAIN_MENU]![txt_MAIN_MENU_REGION]
```

When I run this I get the following error:

"Syntax error in FROM field"

I think I have read somewhere that this is not possible? If someone can perhaps clarify?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one example of why the database structure that you have setup is not a very good idea. Using this sort of design will mean that you have to work much harder to get the database to work properly.

A far better design would be to replace all of your individual tables with one table, and add a field in their that identifies the region. You will then be very easily able to filter this single table on this region identifier.

Having said that, if you **really** want to do it this way, it can be done in VBA. Assuming that `[txt_MAIN_MENU_REGION]` is your combo box, and is populated with your regions:

```
Private Sub txt_MAIN_MENU_REGION_AfterUpdate()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim strSQL As String
    If Not IsNull(Me!txt_MAIN_MENU_REGION) Then
        strSQL = "SELECT STOCK_CODE, [STOCK DESCRIPTION] FROM " & Me!txt_MAIN_MENU_REGION
    End If
    Me!lstRegion.RowSource = strSQL
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "frmRegion!txt_MAIN_MENU_REGION_AfterUpdate", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks, I am throwing a quick DB together so was taking a shortcut here. But I do agree, I am going to rather add another field for each region and rather define the query from there.